# iPhone 4s touchscreen not working on transportation

Tags: ios, iphone, touchscreen

My iPhone 4s' touchscreen is not working properly when I am on the transportation. It does crazy stuff by itself, e.g. if I want to click on app A it clicks on the app B, instead. If I want to open the browser it opens the Message or Call Contacts, etc. Basically, the touchscreen goes crazy when I'm on the moving transportation vehicle. It clicks on the places where I don't click. I just am not able to use it on a mobile vehicle. iOS 9.3.5, 16 GB iPhone 4s. Thanks.

Comment: In any vehicle? Do you have it plugged into a charger? Try with it unplugged?

Comment: @Tetsujin It happens especially in intercity buses. For example, in last month I have travelled with bus between cities and it happened in that bus many times. FYI, that intercity buses are equipped with wi-fi and many other services that I think might be affecting my iPhone 4s, its gyroscope or some other tool in it. Thanks.